# Serial Communication, if statement not working

Tags: arduino-uno, nodemcu, softwareserial, serial-data

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial my (D6,D7); //(Rx,Tx)
String msg;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
my.begin(9600);
}

void gas()
{
  
  Serial.println(msg);
  if (msg == "0")
  {
    Serial.println("Gas Leakage !!");
  }
  if(msg == "1") {
    delay(1);
  } 
}
 
void loop() {
  
  msg = my.readStringUntil('\n');
  gas(); 
}
```

//I am using software serial to exchange data from Arduino UNO to NodeMCU, i am receiving the data correctly but the "if statement condition" is not working with it. how can i make the if statement work?

Comment: Maybe you also have an `\r` in your string. How exactly are you sending the message?

Comment: my problem solved by changing the if (msg == "0") with if (msg[0] == '0') ,, but I don't know why?

Comment: I would guess exactly the reason I stated above

Comment: what does that terminator \r \n means? in serial communication ?

Comment: Please answer the question, how exactly you are sending the message. Then I will write a proper answer to your question. Are you using `Serial.println()`? Or are you forwarding the data from the Serial Monitor set to both line endings?

Comment: yes I am using Serial.println()

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/println/

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Serial.println()` to send the message. That function will add the combination `\r\n` as line ending to your message, which are the ASCII codes for return carriage and newline.

In your receiving code, you read until `\n`, so your message now reads `"0\r"`, which is of course not equal to `"0"`. Thus the if condition will never trigger.

When using `msg[0] == '0'` you are taking the first character out of the string and compare that to the character `'0'` (especially note the difference between `"0"`, which is a string, and `'0'`, which is a single character). Since you are only using the first character of the string, the `\r` is out of the picture; you aren't using it.

**What to do now?**

- You could send your message only with the `\n` character as line ending. For this only use `Serial.print()` instead of `Serial.println()` and add the line `Serial.print("\n");` directly after you send your message.
- You could write your own read-until code and just ditch every occurrence of the `\r` character.
- You can use `msg.trim()` to remove any white space characters at the start or end of your string, including the `\r` at the end. Then you can use the code, that you already wrote.

---

Note, that using `String`s on an Arduino is mostly considered evil. Especially if you want to use the code for a longer period or you are using `String` very often. The memory for a `String` is allocated dynamically, which can easily lead to heap fragmentation. For a better and longer explanation, look at [The Evils of Arduino Strings](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/), a blog entry from Majenko, who is one of our biggest contributors here.